# What statistics should I use to compare percentages?

Tags: correlation, anova, statistical-significance, kruskal-wallis-test

I am trying to see if there is a statistical significant difference between the amount of bycatch in 5 different types of gear used by fishermen. For each gear I have varying number of replicates as there are higher number of fishermen using certains types of gears compared to others. I have converted my raw data into 'percentage of time occurred' in order to compare them. What stats test should i use? I have access to minitab, but I am a novice with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have at least 6 fishermen using each type of gear, you could begin with ANOVA. Since you're working with percentage data (which violates the assumptions of ANOVA), you'll want to logit- or arcsine-transform the data first.

If the ANOVA turns up significant results, you'll want to run a post-hoc test.

This is important: in the ANOVA, you'll want the identity of the individual fisherman to be a [random factor](http://www4.uwsp.edu/psych/cw/statmanual/anovaterms.html).

- [ANOVA using MiniTab](http://people.exeter.ac.uk/SEGLea/misc/mtbanova.html)
- [Logit transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogitTransformation.html)
- [Post-hoc tests in MiniTab](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/4621-Minitab-PostHoc-tests-with-a-random-variable)

Comment: unfortunately, for 2 types of gear I only have 4 fishermen in each, I thought I would just mention that after the results of the analysis. If the data wasn't in percentages but rather expressed as 0.03 (instead of 3%), would i still have to logit? ( ia am a complete novice as you can see!). I don't think my data is normally distributed either, does this affect what stats test I use??

Comment: If the data isn't normally distributed you, could try a non-parametric test, like Kruskal-Wallis. If you went non-parametric with it, you wouldn't need to perform any data transformation on the percentages.

Comment: Done Kruskal-Wallis, and it seems to have worked. Hopefully that'll be ok! Thanks a lot!